# Disabling form submit with character whitelist

Tags: javascript, forms, http-post

I have a form in which I want to disable the submit button if there are any characters other than A-Z, a-z, and 0-9.

---

What I have now is...

```
    <form name=form action=process.cgi method=POST />
    <input type=text name=field1 />
    <input type=password name=field2 />
    <input type=submit value=submit />
    </form>
```

I am trying to make it so that the details are not submitted untill field1 and field2 only have A-Z, a-z, and 0-9

Comment: Don't forget your back-end validation. JS is there only to provide instant feedback for user, not to validate the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="button" id="but" onClick="validate()" Value="Submit">
```

And your js

```
String.prototype.isValid = function(){return /^\w*$/.test(this);}

    function validate() {
    if(document.getElementById('name').value.isValid()){
        alert('valid')   ;             

    } else{
        alert('Invalid')   ;     
    }    
        }
```

check this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PuyZW/)**

Updated to include form submission [**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PuyZW/1/)

2nd Update [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PuyZW/8/)

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing, do you know of a way to disable spaces, and also if it is blank?

Comment: @zggz12 above checks for spaces between entered values and for blank you should try some sort of validation. i will try

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript / JQuery / Server side, to validate text and password with the mentioned regex

```
[A-Za-z\d]+
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot to this question.

I would recommend

1) [javascript regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)
2) [Jquery](http://jquery.com/)

You will use regex to ensure that there are not any spaces etc.
And jquery to disable the button.